SPARQL query that detects triples existing in two graphs
I try to write a SPARQL query to detect duplicated RDF triples that exist in two given graphs (on the same endpoint), but don't know how to do it.
Is it feasible, and if so, how?

SELECT DISTINCT * 
WHERE {
  GRAPH <https://example.com/named-graph-1/> { ?s ?p ?o . }
  GRAPH <https://example.com/named-graph-2/> { ?s ?p ?o . }
}

To find duplicate triples in any two named graphs, you can use variables:
SELECT DISTINCT *
WHERE {
  GRAPH ?namedGraph1 { ?s ?p ?o . }
  GRAPH ?namedGraph2 { ?s ?p ?o . }
  FILTER( STR(?namedGraph1) < STR(?namedGraph2) )
}


Thank you so much! I feel a little stupid given the simplicity of the answer.

@Amleth: You’re welcome :) Even simple things can be non-obvious if one is not used to thinking in SPARQL/graphs. – You may accept this answer so that your question gets marked as solved.
